# Android SDK Error: Version

Tags: android, android-version

I have worked today on a project, which had no errors, and after a sort break, when I re-opened eclipse, I got the following error:

[image: Android SDK version error]

I have tried searching for a solution, but the error is to long in length to find any results.
I even downloaded the new 17 revision, but it didn't help.

Comment: So to enable the rest of us to help: what OS are you running? what version of eclipse? anything else that might be of help. It is unlikely that there was a magical auto update without you knowing.

Comment: My Specs:
Windows 7 32 bit.
Eclipse: Version: 3.7.1
Build id: M20110909-1335

Comment: In addition, when I try to open the SDK manager, I get the following error: The location has not been found(~). And when I try to browse and get it manually from the preferences, It doesn't detect the tools folder although it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets start by verifying the current version of ADT installed. Just in case:

1. Start Eclipse
2. Click Help
3. Click "About Eclipse"
4. Then choose the icon that has the android robot

[image: About Eclipse Dialog]

In the new dialog you will see the ADT version. If this is **NOT** 17 then the error message does not lie and even though you may have tried to upgrade to version 17 it clearly has not. If it has then I would suggest a complete re-install of ADT and the SDK. You can follow the docs here http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

One reason the update may have failed before you start pulling it all apart is that you may need to run eclipse as an administrator. I also find that SDK updates via the SDK manager have to be done as an administrator too.

When going from Eclipse to the SDK Manager I sometimes find that Eclipse has not started it with admin rights even though Eclipse has them. Therefore the update process then fails. I find it best to start the SDK manager with admin rights yourself, and then update the SDK manually and check the error log for any issues (normally the download works but then fails to copy the files for me if I am not in administrator mode).

EDIT/UPDATE:

Have you checked the ADT settings in Eclipse, especially the setting for `SDK Location`? Does it point to your up to date copy of the SDK? If it is having trouble opening the SDK manager then it could be the SDK is broken after attempting an update. I would uninstall it completely then download a fresh copy.

Comment: I have uninstalled it through the windows add/remove programs, but it is still in eclipse. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Restart eclipse after the download.
It shouldn't give you an error

Comment: I restarted it several times.

Comment: You did not state that you had restarted Eclipse afterwards anywhere. Therefore, while obvious, this answer seems legitimate.